# Generate sequence using previous terms sympy

Tags: python, factorial, sympy, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I would like to generate a sequence  such that the previously generated element was included in the next element, I am unsure how to do this.

i.e generate the list such that its items were:

where x is just a Sympy symbol

`[x,(x)*(x+1),(x)*(x+1)*(x+2)]`

rather than `[x,x+1,x+2]`

I'm thinking something like

`k.append(k*(K+o))`

but I keep getting a type error

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the end I just used danodonovan's solution and declared result as a symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using a recursive `lambda` function and a `map` ?

```
>>> fact = lambda x: x == 0 and 1 or x * fact(x - 1)
>>> map(fact, range(4))
[1, 1, 2, 6]
```

and many other ways besides. If you want to return a `string` define your recursive function to return a `string`;

```py
def fact(i):
    if i == 0:
        return 'x'
    else:
        return fact(i - 1) + '*(x+%d)' % i
```

and then

```
>>> map(fact, range(4))
['x', 'x*(x+1)', 'x*(x+1)*(x+2)', 'x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3)']
```

and if you're using `sympy` and think that using strings is an "anti-pattern"

```py
import sympy

def fact(i):
    if i == 0:
        return sympy.Symbol('x')
    else:
        return sympy.Symbol('(x+%d)' % i) * fact(i - 1)
```

produces

```py
>>> map(fact, range(4))
[x, (x+1)*x, (x+1)*(x+2)*x, (x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3)*x]
```

Comment: I wish to return symbols, I can't see how to adapt this.

Comment: Please, oh please, do not suggest using strings in a question about sympy. It is one of the biggest antipatterns in this context.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sympy.RaisingFactorial`:

```
import sympy.RaisingFactorial as RF
from sympy.abc import x
length=3
ans = [RF(x,i) for i in xrange(1,length+1)]
```

Which gives:

```
[x, x*(x + 1), x*(x + 1)*(x + 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`RisingFactorial` is probably the best way, especially if you only want the final term, but you can also do

```
a = [x]
for i in range(1, 5): # Replace 5 with however far up you want to go
    a.append(a[-1]*(x - i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no ready made function, you can define a polynomial expression (not a `Poly`) by it's roots pretty easily...

```
def poly_by_roots(roots, sym):
    return prod(map(lambda x: sym-x, roots))
```

then apply to a list of roots

```
polys = [poly_by_roots(range(a,1), x) for a in range(-5,1)]
```

it's not the most efficient method, that is any which uses the fact that the previous polynomial differs by only `(x+i)`, for example

```
def poch_list(x,n):
    if n==0:
        return [x]
    else:
        val = poch_list(x,n-1)
        return val + [val[-1]*(x+n)]
```

which allows symbolic lengths, which may or may not be a good thing.